# Elixir Ecto/Postgrex outputting weird debug Message on Repository.insert

Tags: elixir, ecto

(Code is over Github at https://github.com/fabianhjr/AseguradoraElixir/tree/fcfeacbee1ec9bc9f59bb01e65743983ae0986d3)

Trying to use Ecto/Postgrex with some models I am getting an unexpected output on Repository insert.(lib/main.ex:63)

```
   62     %Cliente{nombre: nombre, direccion: direccion, telefono: telefono, email: email}
   63     |> Db.insert
```

Getting the following error

```
07:08:32.063 [error] Error in process <0.148.0> with exit value: {#{'__exception__'=>true,'__struct__'=>'Elixir.Postgrex.Error',message=>nil,postgres=>#{code=><<5 bytes>>,file=><<10 bytes>>,line=><<3 bytes>>,message=><<44 bytes>>,routine=><<12 bytes>>,severity=><<5 bytes>>}},[{'Elixir.Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Worker','query!',4,[{file,"lib/ecto/adapters/postg...
```

I connected to the db with pgAdmin, did the schema manually since mix ecto.gen.migration / mix ecto.migrate seem to be broken. (I am starting with elixir so I am doing something wrong probably, I was pointed to check my entry points in mix.exs, I think they are fine) I tried using IO.inspect and it is still quite ugly and unreadable.(Repository.get [Model] [id] doesn't crash, just returns nil)

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update**
Better error message thanks to Jose

```
09:13:04.292 [error] Task #PID<0.151.0> started from #PID<0.135.0> terminating
Function: #Function<20.90072148/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
    Args: []
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL (3D000): database "aseguradora simple" does not exist
        lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/worker.ex:18: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Worker.query!/4
        lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:357: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.use_worker/3
        lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:90: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.insert/3
        lib/ecto/repo/backend.ex:91: Ecto.Repo.Backend.insert/4
        (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:74: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
        (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:19: Task.Supervised.async/3
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:237: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Comment: This is a very horrible error. What happens when you execute this same operation inside `Task.async(fn -> ... existing code ... end) |> Task.await`. Do you at least get a better error?

Comment: Didn't have all the migrations, silly my. Thanks a lot, it really helped me debug this.

Comment: I am glad you fixed it! I am surprised though you got such poor error messages originally. Were you spawning new processes directly? If so, consider using Task.start/Task.start_link for creating new processes, as it will always imply in better error messages. :)

Comment: @FabiánHerediaMontiel please answer your own question and mark that answer as accepted. This lets future visitors quickly find the fix and clearly indicates that the issue was resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @JoséValim why don't you answer with your comment and I mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems something somewhere is spawning a process directly with spawn_link or similar, that's why you are not getting a good error report. The recommended is to use Task.start_link/1 for two reasons:

1. It works in supervision trees
2. You get beautiful log messages when something goes wrong

So I would recommend you to use Task.start_link/1 or Task.async/1 + Task.await/1 if you need a return value. That should give you a better stacktrace and consequently help you understand what is really happening.

PS: There is a chance Erlang 18 will include a way to customize error reports for "bare processes" then the main reason for using a Task will be basically to play embed them in supervision trees.